# Как написать валидатор для цикла while с условием проверки что строка не является числом?

Tags: python

```
string = "a"

while string not string.isdigit():
    print("string is not digit")
```

Comment: Все правильно, только после двоеточия нужно ставить Enter и 4 пробела

Comment: Вы почти у цели. Правильным будет такое условие: `while not string.isdigit()`. Учтите, что это не работает для дробных и отрицательных чисел

Comment: Ещё нужен шаг, где строка как-то меняется или вводится, иначе цикл будет бесконечный ))

Comment: @Пушистик, они там были. Код был неправильно выделен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "a"

while not string.isdigit():
    print("string is not digit")
```

Comment: Благодарю! @Exllent